# How to get the last row in a historic

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I Have this query:

```
SELECT id,
    numero_processo,
    assunto,
    (
        SELECT processo_historico.urgencia
        FROM processo_historico
        WHERE processo_historico.id_processo = processo.id
        ORDER BY processo_historico.id DESC LIMIT 1
     ) as urgencia,
     (
        SELECT processo_historico.nome_resp
        FROM processo_historico
        WHERE processo_historico.id_processo = processo.id
        ORDER BY processo_historico.id DESC LIMIT 1
     ) as nome_resp,
     (
        SELECT processo_historico.user_responsavel
        FROM processo_historico
        WHERE processo_historico.id_processo = processo.id 
        ORDER BY processo_historico.id DESC LIMIT 1
     ) as user_responsavel,
     (
         SELECT processo_historico.data_chegada
        FROM processo_historico
        WHERE processo_historico.id_processo = processo.id
        ORDER BY processo_historico.id DESC LIMIT 1
     ) as data_chegada,
     (
         SELECT processo_historico.distribuicao
        FROM processo_historico
        WHERE processo_historico.id_processo = processo.id
        ORDER BY processo_historico.id DESC LIMIT 1
      ) as distribuicao,
      (
          SELECT processo_historico.despacho
        FROM processo_historico
        WHERE processo_historico.id_processo = processo.id
        ORDER BY processo_historico.id DESC LIMIT 1
      ) as despacho,
      (
          SELECT processo_historico.parecer
        FROM processo_historico
        WHERE processo_historico.id_processo = processo.id
        ORDER BY processo_historico.id DESC LIMIT 1
      ) as parecer    

     FROM processo
```

As you guys can see, too many subqueries to make 1 row of each 'processo' which has the last inserted 'processo_historico'.

How can I improve this? and one more question, how can I put the WHERE like this:

```
WHERE processo_historico.user_responsavel = *userinput*
```

This needs to get me the last 'processo_historico' WHERE 'user_responsavel' is some number.

the relationship between tables is: "processo" 1 x N "processo_historico"

Comment: Can you explain it with example data what you would like to accomplish?

Comment: @Sjoerd so, the relationship between tables is: table "processo" 1 x N table "processo_historico". and I want to know where to put "WHERE" to get the last row inserted on 'processo_historico' which "processo_historico.user_responsavel" is equal some int value

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the multiple sub query to fetch each column to one.

```
SELECT id,
processo.numero_processo,
processo.assunto,
ph.urgencia, 
ph.nome_resp,
ph.user_responsavel,
ph.data_chegada,
ph.distribuicao,
ph.despacho,
ph.parecer     
FROM processo
LEFT OUTER JOIN (    
    select
    processo_historico.urgencia, 
    processo_historico.nome_resp
    ,processo_historico.user_responsavel
    ,processo_historico.data_chegada
    ,processo_historico.distribuicao
    ,processo_historico.despacho
    ,processo_historico.parecer  
    FROM     
    processo_historico 
    WHERE ph.user_responsavel = *userinput*
    ORDER BY processo_historico.id DESC LIMIT 1)
AS ph ON ph.id_processo = processo.id
```

Comment: thank you for help but this sql returns me NULL on all "processo_historico" data...

Comment: @GuilhermePedrazzi - What does the subquery give when run by itself?

Comment: The test for 'userinput' needs to be inside the subquery.